# Expandable list in pdf files

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, report

Can i create an expandable list in pdf files. Expandable list will be of the form :

```
+Item1
+Item2
-Item3
   -Subitem3.1
   -Subitem3.2
+Item4
-Item5
   -Subitem5.1
   -Subitem5.2
   -Subitem5.3
```

Also I need to create the pdf file from Java(I was thinking of using iText, is another library better/easier?). Is this possible. Or is a report in some other standard format(not pdf or html) an easier way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this: I'm the creator of iText, so forgive me for not pointing you to other solutions ;-)

Now for your question: you're asking for dynamic functionality (a tree structure that opens/closes upon user interaction) inside a PDF document.

The most obvious answer is: this isn't possible. When creating PDF, think of paper. Can you print a tree structure on paper that opens/closes when the end user touches the paper? No, you can't, therefore you're asking something that isn't possible in PDF.

The less obvious answer is: it depends. What type of PDF are we talking about?

If you're talking about an interactive XFA form, then you may be able to achieve what you want. The XML Forms Architecture (XFA) is an XML specification that can be used to define interactive forms. When you use XFA, the PDF is nothing more than a container for XML. This XML is rendered dynamically inside Adobe Reader. How to create an XFA form? I only know about two products: Adobe LiveCycle Designer and Avoka Smart Forms Designer.

If you're talking about 'regular PDF', then one option is to embed a swf file. In this case, the tree structure will be rendered by Flash player (which could be a disadvantage, because this might not work with all PDF viewers). Another disadvantage: the tree structure will be confined to a fixed rectangle on a fixed page.

Finally: you can have create such a structure in the bookmarks panel. In PDF terminology, those bookmarks are called Outlines. Obviously, the tree structure won't be a part of the printable content. It will be visible in a separate panel in your PDF viewer.

Comment: Can we get to print expandable list content in PDF with all groups expanded????

If yes then share an example?